# Magic Needed in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have navigation links in `li` placed at the bottom of the page, each of which has an image in itself. On mouse hover, on entering I have animated the li's top as negative of the size of image so that image slides up, and on mouse leaving I have made the top 0.

The requirement includes a `div` which climbs up with each `li`, having some content, and drops down with the `li`. Now, the problem arises here, when I leave `li` to enter the mouse in `div`, the `li` drops taking the `div` with it. I have tried binding `mousemove` event on `mouseleave` which takes the mouse coordinates and check if the mouse is in the `div`, it worked fine but after trying the thing more than 4 or 5 times, it stopped animating the `div` each time, with no error on firebug.

I have tried it with css including the `div` in `li`; but for every `li`, the `div` overlaps all the left `li`'s, otherwise it would have been a piece of cake.

In the code below, the bgIdeas is the `div` referred above.

**Javascript**

```
    a.cache.brand_nav.find("li a").hover(function (c) {
        if (a.isTablet && c.currentTarget.href !== f) d.location = c.currentTarget.href;
        else {
            c = b(this);
            c.stop(true, true).animate({ top: '-' + c.find("img").height() + 'px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
            $('#bgIdeas').stop(true, true).animate({ bottom: '+' + c.find("img").height() + 'px' }, 500, 'easeInCirc', false);
        }
    },
    function () {
        c = b(this);
        $('#bgIdeas').stop(true, true).animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
        c.stop(true, true).animate({ top: '0px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
        clearInterval(myRecFunc);
        $('.bgs').fadeIn(1000).show();
        continueSlideShow();
    });
```

The commented code is the one in which I binded the mousemove event to stop the li from dropping down if pointer is on the div.

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="clearfix">

  <li>
    <a style="top: 0px;" href="#" title="Ideas" class="ideas">
    <span class="top">
        <span class="logo">Ideas</span>
        <span class="description">abc<br>
          Click Here</span>
          <span class="creator"><small>abc</small><br>
          Click Here</span>
    </span>
    <img src="images/abc_thumb.jpg" alt="Ideas">
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a style="top: 0px;" href="#" title="def" class="def">
      <span class="top">
          <span class="logo">Def</span>
          <span class="description">Def<br>
          Click Here</span>
          <span class="creator"><small>Def</small><br>
          Click Here</span>
      </span>
      <img src="images/def_thumb.jpg" alt="Def">
      </a>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a style="top: 0px;" href="#" title="ghi" class="ghi">
      <span class="top">
          <span class="logo">ghi</span>
          <span class="description">ghi<br>
          Click Here</span>
          <span class="creator"><small>ghi</small><br>
          Click Here</span>
      </span>
      <img src="images/ghi_thumb.jpg" alt="ghi">
      </a>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a style="top: 0px;" href="#" title="jkl" class="jkl">
      <span class="top">
          <span class="logo">jkl</span>
          <span class="description">jkl<br>
          Click Here</span>
          <span class="creator"><small>jkl</small><br>
          Click Here</span>
      </span>
      <img src="images/jkl_thumb.jpg" alt="jkl">
      </a>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a style="top: 0px;" href="#" title="mno" class="mno">
      <span class="top">
          <span class="logo">mno</span>
          <span class="description">mno<br>
          Click Here</span>
          <span class="creator"><small>mno</small><br>
          Click Here</span>
      </span>
      <img src="images/mno_thumb.jpg" alt="mno">
      </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If you need magic, I recommend a crystal ball. However, it might help to get an answer if you also post your relevant html. (and if your commented code is not relevant, please remove it)

Comment: the commented code is the one I tried using the mousemove event, just to tell people I have tried this method.

Comment: Html is nothing but a list of <li> having an anchor and an image tag in each. If you insist I can add that too.

Comment: even better if you put it into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (including the `div's` around the `li` so we can see what's going wrong)

Comment: A piece of code is worth a thousand words.  Please include the HTML.

Comment: try doing this with background-image and background-position?

Comment: Also can you post your current CSS